# Intel graphic drivers for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

I looks like they cancelled support. I can't find way to install them and without them I have terrible performance. Is there anything I can do except upgrading?

Comment: What is your system? PC or Mac? Which Inter Graphic card?

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to install any drivers. Intel drivers are installed in Ubuntu by default and are regularly updated through routine system updates.

If you installed Ubuntu 14.04, not 14.04.2, you can upgrade the graphical stack including the Intel drivers and the kernel by running:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

Comment: I have 14.04.2 so I guess this is no go? Also supplied driver is from 2014Q1 stack with does not work very good with my GPU.

Comment: @XperianX If you installed Ubuntu before 14.04.2 was released, you still have an old stack.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 7 months ago not sure with subversion,though I was able to update to newer stack. I did reinstall and it looks like this is not longer possible since they do not support 14.04 anymore. Is there any way to get 2014Q4 stack again?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04.3 here and drivers won't work with my ultradock (T450s), xorg-edgers break transparancy. Very unsatisfying situation, made by canonical.

Comment: xorg-edgers have nothing to do with Canonical. It is a private ppa.

Comment: @Pilot6 Excuse me is it OK to replace utopic with wily in your command?

Comment: @XperianX Could you please tell me why ubuntu does not  `upgrade the graphical stack` with `apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: @Daniyal There is no graphical stack `-lts-wily` yet.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks, so should replace with vivid?

Comment: With vivid there should be one pcakage removed from the coomand. I do not remember which. but you will see in error message.

Comment: @Daniyal I'm not sure why updating does not work but you can update it manually by downloading source code from here https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads and compiling it,it worked for me on xUbuntu 14.04 and LMDE 7.

Comment: Have you tried your answer with Inter graphics devices? I did it with Macbook Air 2013-mid and many configurations of mine broke here http://askubuntu.com/q/779547/25388