# Ubuntu has black stripes and white stripes all over the place

Tags: 14.04, desktop-background

I have an old PC, I just switched my harddrive and I see black stripes on the left side of the monitor, my wallpaper has white stripes all over it, scrambled. Terminal and other applications text are scrambled, however applications like Thunderbird, Chrome etc work fine.

Booting with bootline nomodeset video=vesa has no stripes, but is laggy and is stuck on 1 resolution.

The same thing at the installer of 14.04, except less noticeable on the wallpaper but has black stripes on the right side.

Using iGPU of Intel Core 2 Duo E7400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most certainly a graphics driver issue. You say it's an old PC and using iGPU of E7400.

I'd suggest - now that 15.10 is out - that you try with ubuntu 15.04 or 15.10. As these have **more recent drivers**.

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645080/intel-graphic-drivers-for-ubuntu-14-04) suggests to **update the graphic drivers** with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

There is an altogether different solution: **use a graphics card**. Intel graphics of the E7400 processor generation are not really up to "present standards" to say the least. You'll not like the 3D performance of these processors whether or not you are able to solve the drivers problem. Any $80 graphics card from either ATI or NVIDIA will give you a better experience.

Comment: I was using 15.10 actually, but switched to another pc which is still old but works fine, thanks for your answer tho.