# How to Have Better Intel Graphics Drivers on Macbook?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, 16.04, intel-graphics, macbook

I see many graphical artifacts in using Ubuntu 14.04 on Macbook Air 2013-mid. Doing CTRL-Super-[key] causes often a time-lag and sluttering of the graphics (bad sign of the drivers). There are also other complications of the drivers such as much loading (3-7 seconds) of some basic movements such as moving the window by the former keybinding. Loading does not affect all the time but often (about 1/7).

- 4th generation Intel Core i5 processor with Intel HD graphics 5000
- I just have the defaults in my system: 3rd party packages allowed.

### Ubuntu 14.04

I tried Mark's proposed thread and its code found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/645081/25388) about *Intel graphic drivers for Ubuntu 14.04*

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

Output: many things broke: keyboard-layout changed to Qwerty, `gpointing-device-settings` stopped working, ...
I would like to understand why. 
Why those drivers cause such complications?
Are they just temporary? Should I continue with those drivers?

I do `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` but the problems are not resolved back to default configurations.

### To recover from the damage

How can you uninstall those packages and return to the earlier state? 
I do not understand what the system did so I want to the earlier configuration.

- many reinstall cycles and fixing packages individually until better state reached

---

How can you have better GPU drivers in Ubuntu 14.04 and/or 16.04 on Macbook?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intel graphic drivers for Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/645080/intel-graphic-drivers-for-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Fair enough, vote retracted.

Comment: Would be better to ask about those drivers on the question they came from, I don't see a reason why they would cause such issues.

Comment: On intels website are installers but 14.04 seems not to be supported https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads I don't know why because both 14.10 and 15.04 are, I don't know what else to suggest. In additional drivers, can you activate the microcode driver? It is for Intel CPU but may help a little with this kind of GPU.

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic` I guess but not sure

Comment: I am glad you got it going, if it works out for you, do consider summarizing an answers, this could be good information :)

Comment: @MarkKirby How did you find those packages? Do you have proposals for Ubuntu 16.04? I am experimenting on it now. I manage to get aonly the first package to work.

Comment: Using the 15.10 installer from the intel link https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads combined with this https://allanbogh.com/2016/01/05/ubuntu-16-04-installing-the-intel-graphics-drivers-using-the-intel-graphics-installer-for-linux/ should let you install it with the installer. I have not tried it but it seems sound to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarkKirby's proposal in Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

Attempt in Ubuntu 16.04 where I did not manage to get anything else work

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

His proposal about 15.10 drivers in 16.04 described [here](https://allanbogh.com/2016/01/05/ubuntu-16-04-installing-the-intel-graphics-drivers-using-the-intel-graphics-installer-for-linux/).

Comment: Please, let us know when 16.04 drivers are out!