# Hardware Graphic Accelleration on Asus E403S

Tags: drivers, graphics, asus, lspci

I bought an Asus E403S and I immediatly put on it Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME, this pc has a N3700 Pentium cpu and no video card, I'm wondering if it is normal that CSS animations like a simple font-size-transition have lag with this hardware or I just need to install some kind of driver to provide a better graphic return.

I'm sorry for the newbe question, I'm extremely new with ubuntu, hope sm1 could help.

Thank You

**EDIT**

This is the result of lspci -nnk:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2280] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1bed]
    Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22b1] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1bed]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22dc] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1bed]
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22b5] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1bed]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:1a.0 Encryption controller [1080]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2298] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1bed]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_txe
    Kernel modules: mei_txe
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2284] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1bed]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22c8] (rev 21)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22cc] (rev 21)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:229c] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1bed]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2292] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1bed]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev cb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4c70]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: You should add the output of `lspci -nnk` to the question.

Comment: You could check "Additional Drivers" to see if there is a better option than the i915 driver you are using. Related:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/645080/intel-graphic-drivers-for-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Well, as expected, there is an Intel GPU with the i915 driver. Not sure how much can be expected from that.

Comment: It seems not additional drivers are provided, thank you for replies

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same notebook and as for me the 2d/3d acceleration is working out of the box with xubuntu 16.04. I've experienced a lot of lag with firefox, and visual glitches with chrome, but after an acceleration method change from SNA to UXA, chrome seems to be good. (SNA is default in this case, without a config file).

Edit (or create) /etc/X11/xorg.conf as follows: (ugh, can't format,
should be a tab before each line except the first and the last).

`Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
EndSection`

Restart GDM/XDM/LightDM/etc. and hope for the best! :)