# Where Can I Get ubuntu 14.04 OEM Version for Dell inspiron 15 3552 Laptop?

Tags: 14.04, dell, intel-graphics

Where Can I Get ubuntu 14.04 OEM Version for Dell inspiron 15 3552 Laptop?
My Laptop was came with preloaded ubuntu 14.04 but I deleted that but now no OS is working properly so I just want to go in that preloaded OS.
    I tried ubuntu 14.04, but I'm facing problem as when I'm opening any thing like: Dash Home my laptop screen getting blur or something like hazy & after few seconds my laptop screen going back to the login.
So can anybody help me?

Comment: Ask Dell. But there is no need. You can install a generic Ubuntu release. Some small tuning may be needed.

Comment: There's no "OEM" Ubuntu for Dell and never was. At most a standard Ubuntu and a couple of PPAs.

Comment: Actually when I'm installing any other ubuntu release (eg. ubuntu 14.04) it's not working properly with my system. I facing graphics issue as my laptop screen is getting blur(something like that).

Comment: See http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/dell-isos-for-ubuntu-14-04-and-16-04-for-linux-based-dell-laptops/2687 for pointers, maybe!

Comment: There is http://dell.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/ but I don't know what it's about. There's no obvious iso for downloading.

Comment: "Not working properly" is too vague.

Comment: I tried ubuntu 14.04, but I'm facing problem as when I'm opening any thing like: Dash Home my laptop screen getting blur or something like hazy & after few seconds my laptop screen going back to the login. @Pilot6

Comment: When someone asks for additional information, please add it in the question itself by clicking the edit button.

Comment: You probably need to install a video driver.

Comment: As you said I followed this (http://askubuntu.com/questions/645080/intel-graphic-drivers-for-ubuntu-14-04) but then my whole laptop screen was black. @Pilot6

Answer (score 1):

You can find a suitable release at http://releases.ubuntu.com/ - I would recommend "Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (Trusty Tahr)" (64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image). This works fine with my Dell XPS 15.

According to this list https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/liste_portables_dell, 16.04 seems to be working on DELL inspiron 15 3552.