# Ubuntu 14.04 and Gnome 3.12 , GTK Apps black areas glitch?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, intel-graphics, gtk, gtk3

I asked the same question in the Linux&Unix section, but I suspect that's mainly intended for scripting so I'll leave it here too.

My setup is:

- ubuntu gnome 14.04
- gnome 3.12
- gtk2 (version 2.24.24) and gtk3 (version 3.12.2) installed
- integrated Intel Graphics 4400

Occasionally I experience a strange graphic behavior with some applications: **click-able parts of them are completely black/transparent** and assume their 
**correct colors only if I click on them**.

The 2 pictures below show the before/after with GTKwave (a software I must use for a class in digital systems design).
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vWq3.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaISW.png) few clicks (notice the black bar with no click-able items that persists on the upper right).

This is not the only app which shows this behavior, but it's quite annoying in this case. Also, if I resize the window the bug pops up again and I have to "repaint" the whole thing.

I found only one similar question but that KDE related and I'm using GNOME.

I tried to change the gnome-shell theme back to default (was using numix), but nothing happened.

Any chance I can fix this? I look forward to your suggestion because I'm a little bit stuck at the moment and don't want to run the simulations on a virtual machine.

Thanks in advance,
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the glitch. 
I found the solution here on the forum in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645080/intel-graphic-drivers-for-ubuntu-14-04) question searching in more general therms.
The answer is general as well since it is the

> upgrade of the graphical stack, including the Intel drivers and the kernel

This can be done from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

I still don't know what te particular problem was, but this solved for me.
Hope this helps.

Regards,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that before and I'm the guy who wrote the program.  It's probably something weird going on with whatever your graphics backend is as both of those are areas which are GdkPixmap.  I'm glad to hear it's not just gtkwave.  Note that those areas ignore themes so it's likely not that unless the compositor/renderer has some sort of effect on those areas, for example, setting an alpha channel or something that is not typical with gtk2.

Those areas get copied back to the main area automatically on exposure events from the X server.  I don't know if you're using Wayland or something like that and whatever is going on in Gdk's rendering backend for gtk2 is missing exposure events that copy from gtkwave's private backing store to what is visible onscreen.

In wavearea_configure_event() of wavewindow.c, you'll see a debug printf.  remove the DEBUG() to expose the printf to see if there are configure events being sent to Gdk.  These should occur when a part of the wavearea or signalarea are covered/uncovered/resized/etc.  Resizing seems to indicate to me that configure events are getting lost.

All in all it sounds like an interesting bug in the Gdk backend of gtk2 to me.  If it's something like that you might be able to use Xephyr/Xnest/whatever in order to get a sane X11 representation.  The same goes for launching vncserver and vncviewer in the same session and targeting gtk to that.

NOTE: gtkwave hasn't been converted to gtk3 mainly because gtk3 is missing a lot of function I need and rewriting huge chunks of the viewer is not a priority on my to-do list.

-Tony

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot Tony for your great effort in building GTKwave. We all appreciate this! 
Thanks a ton for the fast reply, I did what you said and this is the log after a resize:

'GTKWave Analyzer v3.3.85 (w)1999-2017 BSI

[0] start time.
[40000] end time.
WaveWin Configure Event h: 1, w: 1
WaveWin Configure Event h: 484, w: 672
WaveWin Configure Event h: 484, w: 671
WaveWin Configure Event h: 484, w: 670'

Nothing logged while clicking to get back the lost images.
I didn't understand the last part of the reply, but it's my fault: I must try to find a way to use Xnest.

Comment: If possible, try and only post an answer when you're sure that it will work for the OP. If you need clarification on anything, comment it instead and then use that information for your answer. Due to your reputation, you cannot comment yet, so I would recommend building up reputation off of edits or answers that don't require clarification from the author.

Answer (score 0):

Such graphical glitches are in my experience usually related to the graphics driver - and that's a wide field. Nevertheless similar symptoms have been reported [fixed](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88584) (or at least worked around) by adding `COGL_ATLAS_DEFAULT_BLIT_MODE=framebuffer` to your /etc/environment file.
Log out and log in again and check if the variable is set correctly via `env | grep -i cogl`.

It's a long shot due to the many components (software as well as hardware) involved, but I guess worth trying since it is simple. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks b3nmore for the answer. I looked at the link you provided and it seems a lot of people are having troubles with gtk apps, I didn't find this back when the bug first appear. 
I did what you suggested (and checked the variable), but even after reboot nothing changed unfortunately.